# Find the rest of days else days in month c#

Tags: c#

Display the rest of days if i select any date otherwise days in month using datetimepicker tool in c#.
eg.

if i am **selecting the date like 12-may-2011** in datetimepicker the

textbox should tells the remaining days= 20 because 11-may-2011 should take. i didn't

select any date so days will be = 31.

i have tried to show days in month by using this code

```
days.Text = DateTime.DaysInMonth(lndate.Value.Year, lndate.Value.Month).ToString();
```

but i want to show both rest of days otherwise days in month

Comment: Is this homework? What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

use **[System.DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)**, it returns the number of days in the specified month and year.

```
 int may = 5;
 int totaldaysinthismonth = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2011, may)

 // compute here what you need
```

note:

> i didn't select any date so days will be = 31

I reccomend **not** to use this rule but instead return null and display e.g. n/a.
31 is NOT a default value for days in a month. This can confuse the users in months like february, april, june, september etc...